# Get positioning (as CGrect) of Tab Bar Icon In swift 4

Tags: animation, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, cgrect

I'm trying to get the exact coordinates (as CGrect) of a specific icon in a tab bar controller in swift 4. I'm trying to create a minimizing "gene" effect into a specific icon at the bottom, but I cant seem to be able to reference the icon size/frame/coordinates in any way. This is needed for the animation end point.

Any insight on this?

Thanks

Comment: refer this to animate icon in tabbar https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar